# How to I go about vertically aligning these rows in bootstrap?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, bootstrap-5

The main suggestion I've found is to add d-flex and align-items-center to the container however this makes my rows appear side by side. So I'm wondering if there is another way to vertically center the rows or if there is some trick to it.

```
import React from "react";

function Projects() {
return (
    <div className="home">
        <div className="container central align-items-center">
            <div className="row justify-content-center my-auto">
                <div className="col-3">
                    <img
                        src="/assets/motherboard.jpg"
                        className="img-fluid"
                        alt="Green motherboard"
                    />
                </div>
                <div class="col-5">
                    <h1 class="font-weight-light">Home</h1>
                    <p>
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and

                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row justify-content-center my-auto">
                <div className="col-3">
                    <img
                        src="/assets/motherboard.jpg"
                        className="img-fluid"
                        alt="Green motherboard"
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="col-5">
                    <h1 className="font-weight-light">Home</h1>
                    <p>
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and

                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row justify-content-center">
                <div className="col-3">
                    <img
                        src="/assets/motherboard.jpg"
                        className="img-fluid"
                        alt="Green motherboard"
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="col-5">
                    <h1 className="font-weight-light">Home</h1>
                    <p>
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and

                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
);
}

export default Projects;
```

The css I'm using is here:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Assistant&display=swap');

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen',
  'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue',
  sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, 'Courier New',
  monospace;
}
.central {
  height: 87.5vh;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Assistant', Arial, serif;
  font-size: xxx-large;

}

.home {
  background-image: url("../public/assets/computer.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mqud7134/

Comment: Can you clarify what you want?

Comment: I was trying to figure out how to make the three elements with class row appear in the vertical center of their container.

Answer (score 0):

As far as What I have understood from the preface, I think you need to vertically align each of the div in a column.

You can use the following style to the container class:

```
import React from "react";

function Projects() {
return (
    <div className="home">
        <div className="container central align-items-center" 
           style={{ display:"flex", flexDirection:"column", flexWrap:"nowrap", justifyContent:"center",     
                      alignItems:"center"}}>

        .  
        . 
        . 
        </div>
    </div>
);
}

export default Projects;
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Seems the problem was that I wasn't specifying the flex direction.